# C++ Toggle to hold left click down?

Tags: c++, click

How do I make a tiny program that holds down left click, while toggleable through a key? I can make it toggle the leftmousebutton to click constantly but I have no clue on how to make it hold down.

```
void Clicker2()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('U')) // U toggles on
        {
            click = true;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState('I')) //I toggles off
        {
            click = false;
        }

        if (click == true)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't send `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` right after `DOWN` event. Send it at the moment, when you want to stop holding button

Comment: Also, `click == true` doesn't make sense if `click` is `bool`. You can just use `if (click) { ... }`. But better to rename on `mouseIsClicked`

Answer (score 0):

When using toggles you want to check the return value of GeyAsyncKeyState(), the least significant bit specifically, you do this by doing a bitwise AND with the result.

I have simplified your code, and converted it to using SendInput() which is what is recommended.

```
int main()
{
    INPUT input{ 0 };
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;

    bool bClick = false;

    while (true)
    {
        //toggles it on and off
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('U') &1)
            bClick = !bClick;

        if (bClick)
        {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
        else
        {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```